# GLSL geometry shader using lines_adjacency

Tags: glsl, geometry-shader

I am writing a GLSL geometry shader and I am trying to use the `lines_adjacency` input layout but it isn't working. My first pass-though test using the `lines` input layout works fine:

```
// GLSL GEOMETRY SHADER
#version 410

layout (lines) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 2) out;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

but when I switch to `lines_adjacency` input it doesn't draw anything:

```
// GLSL GEOMETRY SHADER
#version 410

layout (lines_adjacency) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 2) out;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

I know I'm not actually using the adjacency points here but I will need them eventually. I am a GLSL novice so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did change your input vertices to provide adjacency data, right? Because OpenGL doesn't parse your vertex data to figure out what is adjacent to what. The adjacency types exist to allow *you* to tell the shader about adjacent info. So you must provide that data.

In short, you can't render with the exact same attributes and index data with an adjacency geometry shader. Nevermind the fact that your `glDraw*` calls need to use `GL_LINES_ADJACENCY` instead of `GL_LINES`.

Comment: I was passing in four points as a GL_LINE_STRIP, I assumed that would imply adjacency. I didn't know about GL_LINES_ADJACENCY, I will try that next.